# Data Structure to use in Java

Tags: java

What data stucture should i use in Java to store word frequencies of every word in its sentence as well as its frequency in another sentence i.e. pairwise. Every node must have 2 frequencies one its own and one of its neighboring sentence. This must be repeated for every pair of sentences in a document. Its use it to find out standard cosine similarity later.

Comment: What do you mean by `neighboring sentence` ? Does it mean the one sentence on left and the one on right ? or it means every other sentece than the current one ?

Comment: It means every other sentece than the current one!

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a linked list:

```
public class SentenceOccurencies {
    // Key is the word, Value the count
    public Map<String, Integer> occurrencies = new HashMap<String Integer>();
    public SentenceOccurrencies neighbour;
}
```

Feel free to add accessors / mutators and the like.

Answer (score 0):

An inverted index is the best storage for Information Retrieval techniques.  So you have a Map from words to where they occur, and how many times.

So for two sentences:

The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
The lazy dog slept while the fox jumped.

turns into:

```
brown -> {1:1}
dog -> {1:1, 2:1}
fox -> {1:1, 2:1}
jumped -> {1:1, 2:1}
lazy -> {1:1, 2:1}
over -> {1:1}
quick -> {1:1}
slept -> {2:1}
the -> {1:2, 2:2}
while -> {2:1}
```

You can then just go through the map and extract the information you need. The good thing about this structure is that you can store many more than just two sentences, efficiently!

Comment: Thanks! Could u elaborate on the code or the data structure please. And also how do i find standard cosine similarity of these 2 sentences after this?

Comment: I really think you should try to implement this yourself, otherwise you will learn nothing.  I have given you enough information to make a start - if you get stuck post what you have done.